# Meaning of 引く in ひょっとして俺が一発で正解引いたから、怒ってるのか？

Tags: meaning

im having trouble figuring out the significance of 引く in ひょっとして俺が一発で正解引いたから、怒ってるのか？

Is it something like "pulled (the correct answer) out of thin air" kind of meaning?

None of the definitions on jisho.org seem to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!!

I guess it's originally derived from "くじ" and "おみくじ" (kind of lottery/fortune). When I was a child, there were many "くじ" in Japanese traditional festival. It has many random papers in a box and we put a hand into the box and pick up one. This action is usually called "引く" (pull, draw) in Japanese.
I found an exact phrase in English "Draw lots" which can be directly translated to "くじを引く" [verb] or "くじ引き" (To draw lots) [noun].

These are images of drawing lots.
https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%81%8F%E3%81%98%E5%BC%95%E3%81%8D&sxsrf=ALeKk00YO-sWkTY9jGWUCEDNa3krPuVDDw:1589082202861&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTpeHBsKjpAhXDBIgKHcoJDUcQ_AUoAnoECAwQBA&biw=1375&bih=860

In your original example 「ひょっとして俺が一発で正解引いたから、怒ってるのか？」, I sense 'fortunate', 'chance', or 'happening' meaning from '引く' because it reminds me to "くじ". The talker would think the reason to get the correct answer was not intentional.
Besides this, "一発で" directly means 'one shot' or 'one time'. We can guess that the talker would have got the correct answer at first trial under the lower probability situation.

By the way, there is a phrase "引きが強い" in Japanese. This is directly translated to 'strong to draw' but actually means 'very lucky'. I think this "引く" also comes from "くじ引き".